# Do azure eventHub binding(Java) supports partitionKey for @EventHubOutput?

Tags: java, azure-eventhub

I could find a document or example of eventhub  output binding supporting a partitionKey. The below link says it is an option for trigger metadata however there is no java example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---event-metadata

Did I miss anything in this document or its still not supported?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example about how to use trigger metadata, you could refer to the below code or you could go to the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/blob/ec6ef3e43421a0c30a9f65b608dd86112a6a083d/endtoendtests/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/functions/endtoend/EventHubTriggerTests.java) check the code. The below is my test code.

```
public class Eventhubtest {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when an event is received from Event Hub.
     */
    @FunctionName("Eventhubtest")
    public void run(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "message", eventHubName = "myevent", connection = "EventHubConnection", cardinality = Cardinality.MANY)String message,
        @BindingName("SystemPropertiesArray") SystemProperty[] systemPropertiesArray,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Event Hub trigger function executed."+message);
        context.getLogger().info("SystemProperties for message[0]: EnqueuedTimeUtc=" + systemPropertiesArray[0].EnqueuedTimeUtc +" Offset=" +systemPropertiesArray[0].Offset+" PartitionKey="+ systemPropertiesArray[0].PartitionKey);



    }
    public static class SystemProperty {
        public String SequenceNumber;
        public String Offset;
        public String PartitionKey;
        public String EnqueuedTimeUtc;
    }
}
```

And here is the result. You could find the `PartitionKey` is available in the pic.

[image]